# WC Использованные купоны

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

На странице Мой аккаунт выводятся все доступные купоны для пользователя.

Хочу сделать так, что если купон был использован, то к нему добавляется класс `used`.

Код взял из плагина [Smart Coupons for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wt-smart-coupons-for-woocommerce/) и поставил условие, но оно не работает, почему?

Вот тут выводится код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код и условие:

```
<div class="wt-mycoupons">
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
    if( WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon->post_title ) && is_checkout() ) {
        echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon used'><span class='ico'></span>$coupon->post_title</li>";
    } else {
       echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon'><span class='ico'></span>$coupon->post_title</li>";
    }

}
?>
```

А это полная его форма, как в плагине.

```
<?php
// If this file is called directly, abort.
if (!defined('WPINC')) {
   die;
}


global $current_user, $woocommerce, $wpdb;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // grab the logged in user
$user_id = $current_user->ID; // grab the logged in users id
$email = $current_user->user_email;


$couponlist = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `" . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta`.`post_id` FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta` WHERE `" . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta`.`meta_key` LIKE 'customer_email' AND `" . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta`.`meta_value` LIKE '%" . $email . "%'");
$couponarrayfinal = array();  //Create an array of the ids so we can use wp_query to more quickly grab the data
// Add the ids to the array in a foreach loop
foreach ($couponlist as $key => $row) {

$value = $row->post_id;
$couponarrayfinal[] = $value;
}

$couponargs = array(
'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
'post__in' => $couponarrayfinal,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => '-1'); // Create a new query to run thruogh the arguments
$coupons = get_posts($couponargs); // Create a second loop linked to that query
?>
<div class="wt-mycoupons">
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
        if( WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon->post_title ) && is_checkout() ) {
            echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon used'><span class='ico'></span>$coupon->post_title</li>";
        } else {
           echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon'><span class='ico'></span>$coupon->post_title</li>";
        }

    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Опишите в вопросе где и как вызывается этот код.

Comment: @KAGG Design описал вроде как вы просили.

Comment: Ну а чего вы хотите. Делаете вывод в my-account, а условия ставите, которые работают только в корзине и только на чекауте.

Comment: @KAGG Design а как тогда мне проверить был ли использован купон?

Comment: У купона как объекта есть куча полей и методов. Что конкретно подразумевается - был использован пользователем или общий лимит достигнут?

Comment: @KAGG Design общий лимит достигнут скорее всего, вы правы, у меня в настройках на одного пользователя разрешено использовать только один раз купон. Как такое реализовать не подкажите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$coupon_time = new WC_Coupon( $coupon->ID );
$used_count = $coupon_time->get_usage_count();

if ($used_count == '1') {
   echo 'Использован';
}
```